# Serious problems after 15.10 upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, laptop, hp, 15.10

Okay revising....
I upgraded my computer from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.10. It used to load right away but now after the Ubuntu load screen I get:

[ OK ] started lab/ postfix mail transport agent.

[ OK ] more text

```
  I don't want to copy it all down on my iPod but it continues this way for sometime. Two notable changes since my last post are these two fails:
```

[ FAILED] failed to start lsb: init-script for system wide fetchmail daemon.

```
And three more down:
```

[ FAILED] failed to start lsb: apparmor initialization.

After this it says okay or nothing at all next to the lines, then the bottom message has changed a lot. At frat it said something about starting lightdm but at the end it said "and deal with any changes..p link was shut down" i cant find exact links anymore but i was told to purge xorg and lightdm so I did that and reinstalled them as well as entering

"sudo gdm"

Now I reboot again and now the last line starts with a green OK but says

"started gnome display manager..... And deal with any system changes..p link was shut down....."

And just stays there. BUT now I can't CTRL-ALT-F#. A few hours after that, on another attempt to get access to Virtual terminal, it said

"Stopping user manager for uid 125...d dealt with any system changes..p link was shut down......"

NOWWW last night I booted into recovery (gave up is more like it) and saved all my data. It's a matter of principle to fix it now. The message at the end has now changed to say:

[ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager.ally collect and submit kernel crash signatures.....

And it's hanging out there mocking me. I hope I've made this easier to read. I'm on an iPod so my fat fingers can do only so much. If you need anything else I can get it for you, I can access recovery and mount my private drive so the data hasn't been destroyed. Thanks in advance.

My computer is an HP elitebook 6930p intel core 2 vpro with no after market anything.

EDIT -- I wanted to include information that may or may not help.

I'm running kernel 3.16.0-49-generic. 
Ubuntu 15.10 'willy'

Comment: Okay, so continuing to reboot isn't going to help. I know this is super frustrating, and probably also frightening, but if there is any way that you can 1) Point to other instructions that you have found or 2) edit this so that it is a little easier to read, that will help folks here help you figure out what is going on.

Comment: If I had a computer this would be easier but ill give it a shot.

Comment: Al patience has left. Trying to mount an external 1T to move a few more things and it won't mount. I made a directory for it but now at the point where I mount it idk what format it is; NTFS, fat32... I need to know these things and without another computer an only one in recovery idk how to find out. Thank in advance...again!

Comment: Root access + mplayer = Simpsons tenth Halloween special.