# How do I turn on networking in recovery mode?

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, data-recovery, hp, recovery-mode

I recently posted about messing my system up here.

[Serious problems after 15.10 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694683/serious-problems-after-15-04-upgrade).

I got the system booted into recovery mode, im going to try fixing packages and dependencies but I have no Internet. I've tried entering "ifconfig eth0 up; dhclient eth0" and the dhclient is done when I run "jobs -l" but I still can't connect. I'm using a wifi modem, no access Ethernet cords

Answer (score 2):

I never figured out my wifi but I got on with an Ethernet by running ifconfig eth0 up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an option called <kbd>network</kbd> in the Recovery Menu. Use this to start your network.

Comment: I just have that a try and got this.

Comment: Aorry about that. I got this.  Error getting authority: error initializing authority: could not connect: no such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1) ifup: failed to open lockfile /run/network/. Ifstate.lock: no such file or directory. Trying to start network manager.....       And I'm stuck there. Sorry about formatting in on an iPod.

Comment: Ok that command finished and I booted into recovery and ran ifconfig wlan0 up and my network light is on but I've still got no access to the network. How would I find my modem and enter the password.