# Boot Failure counter

Tags: grub2

I have to modify Ubuntu booting scenario for my own application. I want to count number of times default boots failed continuously, and if it happens for some times (let say 5), it should automatically choose recovery mode.

Probably I have to edit GRUB2 configuration. Or low level programming of Grub2 etc. I am new in this area so any reading material or other suggestions are appropriated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: AFAIK GRUB does not store any information on a particular boot (http://superuser.com/questions/380646/permanently-save-changes-on-grub-menu), so you might need to modify the GRUB program as such. Good luck! Or do you want to select a particular kernel version as default?

Comment: David I have edited the question hopefully it will help now. So, I don't have any logs or errors.
@Melebius I learned how to select a particular kernal version but don't know how to do it on a condition which is the specified counter.

Comment: If you're having boot problems, why don't you tell us about your problem, and lets fix THAT problem... instead of creating workarounds.

Comment: @heynnema Actually this is the original task not workaround. I want to remotely manage the system, so whenever normal boot fails I want system to boot in recovery mode.

Comment: @AshishSultania Are you aware that [networking is disabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694816/how-do-i-turn-on-networking-in-recovery-mode) in the recovery mode? To gain remote control of the boot process and recovery mode, you should get a [KVM switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch) with [IP connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch#KVM_over_IP_.28IPKVM.29).

Comment: @Melebius, you are correct by default network in disabled, yeah IP switches could be one solution. Other solution I am thinking is to running a script by default (init processes) which will enable networking.

Comment: I need this answered for my embedded device scenario. I can't assume customers will fix the boot problems. I must support fallbacks. This question is valid.